USB Type C mobile phone charger Design using MPQ4242-AEC1
I am planning to design a USB type C charger for my bike. This is the first time I am designing a USB charger. I decided to use MPQ4242-AEC1 from MPS.
A 12 V will be coming from my battery. As per my knowledge the battery should be able to provide a current of 3 A or more. Please correct me if I am wrong.
The output range of this IC as per spec is 3.3-22.5 V output voltage (VOUT) range. Will it be able to provide these voltages from a 12 V rail?
Below is my block diagram.

Do I need to add any protection circuitry between the IC and battery.
Can I directly implement the below circuit.
Any special precaution's needs to be taken.

Don't e-bikes usually have significantly higher battery voltages from 18V and up to 48V somewhere? Is it a battery cell or a battery pack? Is there a BMS and if so where?

I have a 12V Auxiliary battery. That will power some necessary functions when vehicle is off. When vehicle is on my board will get 12V from BMS.Aux battery is 12V 9Ah


A 12 V will be coming from my battery. As per my knowledge the battery should be able to provide a current of 3 A or more. Please correct me if I am wrong.

At 20V/3A output (I don't know if the chip is able to deliver this level of power – downloading the datasheet requires registration. sigh) the input current will be more than 5 Amps. And since the battery voltage decreases as it discharges (unless it'll be recharged constantly during the operation) the current demand will be even higher. So, make wiring from the battery to the circuit for more than 5 Amps.

The output range of this IC as per spec is 3.3-22.5 V output voltage (VOUT) range. Will it be able to provide these voltages from a 12 V rail?

Yes. The IC, apparently, can work in both buck and boost modes. The internal switches are controlled by the chip's control circuitry for different scenarios.

Do I need to add any protection circuitry between the IC and battery.

Yes. Apart from what is mentioned in shafeeq's answer, you should at least add a reverse polarity protection, preferably a MOSFET-based ideal diode as the current demand can be really high in your application. Without a reverse polarity protection, a small mistake can cause really big problems such as blowing up the entire circuit and maybe destruction of the battery. So you should add a fuse as well.

Can I directly implement the below circuit.

I'd also make use of the ENABLE functionality which is a really handy feature. When the battery is connected the circuit will run straight away, and keep running as long as the battery is connected, so you may want to keep the charger under control externally. This may also allow you to remove the battery (or disconnect it) safely.

"So you should add a fuse as well." That's tricky given the charger current. It will consume a lot more current when charging than when in use. And battery chargers obviously need something smarter than a fuse for monitoring current anyway.

For battery in automotive systems, the voltages can go higher or lower than the specified voltage. for example, for load dump scenarios the voltage can go upto 87V for a 12V systems. Similarly for inductive load disconnection, the voltage can go upto -100V. Like this for an automotive system, there will be scenarios in which the voltage can go higher or lower. So you have to provide protection for your circuit against these transients and surges. I have only mentioned few scenarios. There are multiple other scenarios also. ISO 7637 and ISO16750-2 explains these situation and expected transient waveforms. These standards explains the waveforms and test conditions for a commercial products. But you can refer the waveform details and provide adequate protection against it.
You can get protection ICs from various manufacturers which will support protection against all kind of transients and surges for automotive systems.

Mine is an eV .May I know do I need to consider all the scenarios mentioned by You

Depending on requirements, just adding a (bipolar) TVS, a MOSFET for polarity protection and a big bulk cap might be good enough. There's some nice full-blown "surge stopper" IC but that might be overkill for an e-bike. There's no starter or alternator etc that can cause mischief in the form of big surges.
